# Excel VB- Hyperllink in first sheet resthide

Tags: vba, excel

I have one workbook which has 110 worksheets.

First sheet is main which contains hyperlinks to other sheets.
I need to write a code that should hide other sheets except first main sheet.
After completing my work on it again it should go to first sheet and rest other hide.
 i got the below code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim sh As Worksheet
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
If sh.Name <> "Summary" Then
sh.Visible = xlSheetHidden
End If
Next sh
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Select Case Target.Address
Case "$A$1"
Sheets("100% Complete").Visible = True
Sheets("100% Complete").Activate
Case "$A$2"
Sheets("Almost Complete").Visible = True
Sheets("Almost Complete").Activate
End Select
End Sub
```

But for this i have to write 110 cases. anything that can avoid this or replace with case?

Comment: You could have the sheet name you want to unhide in the cell you are double-clicking on or in an offset location from that cell, eg if you store the name of the sheet in column D and you are clicking on column A, If Target.Row = 1 Then sheets(target.offset(0,3).value).Visible = true. this is untested, just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
Dim x As Integer

With Target
    x = InStr(.Range, "!")
    If x > 0 Then
         Worksheets(Left(.Range, x - 1)).Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Else
         Worksheets(.Range).Visible = xlSheetVisible
    End If
End With
End Sub
```